# Preventing css inheritance in injected iframe with different domain?

Tags: javascript, iframe

[How to stop Injected HTML-div / CSS from inheriting styles ? (Internet Explorer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172221/how-to-stop-injected-html-div-css-from-inheriting-styles-internet-explorer) Reading that question, it seems that iframe being usedto prevent injected element on the page from inheriting css.

My only concern is, that I need to communicate with this injected iframe, so will not include an src.

`<iframe>my widget don't want to inherit css from outside page.</iframe>` would injecting that to a current page work properly? or does the src need to have a completely different domain than the current page it is on.

Comment: Why not simply use the second solution? CSS inheritance is usually a good feature, and I'm not sure why you wouldn't want to style to popup-div properly anyway.

Comment: @Bergi, for example, when you are developing a chrome extension. the second solution sometimes will not work as well as an iframe. but the biggest need for me is the ability co communicate with such iframe

Comment: Well, if you're developing a chrome extension then you should be familiar with cross-context communication anyway, wouldn't you?